# Alignment of :before and :after for two-line span

Tags: html, css

I am looking or a way to include two images left and right to a title span. The problem I am facing is, that this title will in some cases be stretched across two lines, however not always. I do not want to include two extra elements before/after or after the title but am instead looking for a way to achieve what I am trying without adding new elements to the code. I was therefreo hoping to use :before and :after. This is what I came up with:

```
.block-title:before { position:absolute; content:""; display:inline-block; width:28px; height:14px; margin:2px 0 0 -36px; background:url(../images/sidebar_ornament_l.png) no-repeat 0 0; }
.block-title:after { position:absolute; content:""; display:inline-block; width:28px; height:14px; margin:2px 0 0 9px; background:url(../images/sidebar_ornament_r.png) no-repeat 0 0; }
```

While this will work great, if the title is only one line, titles that will take up two lines, will not behave the way, I would want them to, but instead will look like this:

[image: title wrong]

I have tried everything I could think of, to make the :before and :after pseudoelements behave as I want them to, changing position and display, chaing the actual text span position, etc but just couldn't achieve what I want to.

Since I want the two images to align next to the actual text span, a single background image won't work. The spacing between the text and the image would be too big in some cases, which will look odd. Is there a way to make this work, so I will end up with something like this for two line titles:

[image: title corrected]

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, this is a general concept, i need your full code to provide a specific answer.

Anyway, [**check this demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/gionaf/hSkhK/)

HTML:

```
<span class="block-title">Some text is here</span>
<hr>
<span class="block-title">Some more text<br>is here</span>
<hr>
<span class="block-title">Even<br>more text<br>is here</span>
```

CSS:

```
.block-title {
    position:relative;
    display:inline-block;
    text-align:center;
    padding:0 34px; /* width of your ornament + 6px per each side,
                        adjust to your actual layout */
}
.block-title:before, .block-title:after {
    content:" ";
    width:28px;
    height:14px;
    position:absolute;
    top:50%;
    margin-top:-7px; /* half of ornament's height */
}
.block-title:before {
    background:url(../images/sidebar_ornament_l.png) no-repeat 0 0;
    left:0;
}
.block-title:after {
    background:url(../images/sidebar_ornament_r.png) no-repeat 0 0;
    right:0;
}
```

Comment: EDIT: I guess the problem of the two ornaments not aligning next to the span, if the span consists of several words that are stretched across two or more lines, could only be fixed by inserting manual breakrules - or is there another way maybe? See your modified demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/hSkhK/6/

Comment: @loeffel to me they look aligned. What browser / version are you using? And what's your goal?

Comment: Ok @loeffel, removing "display:inline-block;" from the pseudo-elements worked for me (FF12), [check my updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gionaf/hSkhK/)

Comment: I can see it working in your fiddle, I am not sure why it will not work on my page. Maybe because I am populating the span using php, although I am not sure, why this would be a problem. I will play around with this some more but sofar I have only found one occurrence on my page where this is even noticable, so if it won't work, I guess I can live with that...

Comment: Don't think php could be the problem...may you give me your page's url @loeffel ?

Comment: I am testing this on a local xampp install - I tried making this accessible via dyndns before but never succeeded. If you are willing to wait a bit more, I will have these changes on my live page and would be happy to share this url with you.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17711/discussion-between-loeffel-and-gionaf)

Answer (score 0):

If you apply it to a span, rules ok. I made this code (i have changed de image) http://jsfiddle.net/sSEDz/

Comment: Sorry, i misunderstund the question :-/